# How does an Abbe refractometer actually work?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, reflection, refraction

I'm now in the process of writing a report on a lab work i did with an Abbe refractometer.

In all sources i found the working principle of this refractometer is described as such:

"Light shines into a illuminating prism who's side that contacts the sample is roughed so light scatters uniformly in all direction into the sample. The sample is held between the illuminating prism and the refraction prism (RP). Rays that hit the sample/RP interface at an angle large than the critical angle of the interface suffer total internal reflection (TIR) and thus do not penetrate into the refracting prism. This creates a zone in the refracting prism where there is a shadow. The angle of that shadow depends on the refractive index (RI) of the sample, and it can be measured by adjusting the light/shadow line".

Additionally, some sources explicitly say that the RI of both prisms must be larger than the RI of the sample. Critically, i did not find any source that said otherwise.
If this is the case, how is it possible for there to be TIR in the sample/RP interface if the RP's RI is larger than the sample's?

Furthermore, i used https://phydemo.app/ray-optics/simulator/ to simulate the apparatus. I found that a shadow zone only formed when the condition: "prism's RI > sample's RI" was met. Of course in this situation there was no TIR.

[image]

In fact, forcing the situation where there is TIR, absolutely no shadow zone was created.
[image]

Can someone explain to me how this actually works then? Is there something i am getting wrong? I'm almost sure there is because even manufacturer pages say it works with TIR... But still, it is very confusing!

Comment: found a website that explains how it works: http://www.refractometer.pl/critical-angle-refractometer  it is about light that gets refracted into the RP at the critical angle, so 90° from sample into RP, then inside RP that corresponds to critical angle.